# Confused by use of `from` and `to` params in Android SimpleAdapter class

Tags: android, android-listview

The official Android docs say the following:

```
from    A list of column names that will be added to the Map associated with each item.
to      The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.
```

I've accomplished this as follows:

```
final String[] from = new String[] {"TEXT1", "TEXT2"};
final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
a = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, resource, from, to)
```

I'm able to set data in the view just fine, but im extremely confused as to why the `from` parameter is necessary. Why not just supply a list of xml resources? Why do a list of (column names?) need to be passed in as well?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

> The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.

This means the values in the `from` parameter will be set in the corresponding views in the `to` parameter. According to the [`SimpleAdapter` Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), if the views are `TextView`s, then a list of `String`s is expected, and will be bound to the `TextView`s by calling [`setViewText(TextView, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewText(android.widget.TextView,%20java.lang.String)).